# Error receiving while running queries with union although running them separately working - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query like below:

```
Select
    CPrimaryGroup = t.PrimaryGroup,
    CSecondaryGroup = t.SecondaryGroup, 
    CMed = dbo.median(t.Days),
    CPerc90th = dbo.Percentile90(t.Days)
from    
    myTable t
group by 
    t.PrimaryGroup, t.SecondaryGroup

UNION

Select
    CPrimaryGroup = 'TOTAL',
    CSecondaryGroup = 'TOTAL', 
    CMed = dbo.median(t.Days),
    CPerc90th = dbo.Percentile90(t.Days)
from    
    myTable t

UNION

Select
    CPrimaryGroup = t.PrimaryGroup,
    CSecondaryGroup = 'TOTAL', 
    CMed = dbo.median(t.Days),
    CPerc90th = dbo.Percentile90(t.Days)
from    
    myTable t
group by 
    t.PrimaryGroup
```

When I execute all the queries separately, they are working and returning correct results. However, when I run them all together by using a union keyword between them, it is not working and giving me this error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "Percentile90":
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException:
>   at Percentile90.Accumulate(SqlDouble value)

My aim is to receive an output like (numbers just assumed, don't rely on):

```
primaryGroup secondaryGroup median percentile
X            Y              10     12
X            Z              15     22
Total        Total          12.5   18
X            Total          12.5   20
...
...
```

I could not see my mistake here. How can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: thanks but it didnt solve.

Comment: Please provide sample data and your func definion with http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What is the Percentile90 function doing? Is that a CLR?

Comment: it is finding percentile of a list. Example {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, percentile is 9th element = 9. When percentile fields are comment out, same error existing for median. This functions are all working fine everywhere, which makes me think there should be something else here

Comment: @ErayBalkanli may be You should replace Union With UNION ALL ?

Comment: The error message explicitly states your function. If I were going to debug this I would start with the function. It also sounds like that function is likely a CLR function. Maybe you are passing it a NULL and the function can't handle it? You are going to have to post some details other than your query here. Start with the contents of that function.

Comment: Is the function CLR? the error looks like a .NET error.

Comment: It looks like what you are doing could be simplified with `group by rollup (t.PrimaryGroup, t.SecondaryGroup)` btw.

Comment: Your error is a .NET error, and not a SQL error.   You would have to post your .NET code for anybody to be able to help you.